# auth()->login($user) is not giving required results

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-socialite

I am using php laravel to write login using Facebook and Google. For that i need user to login manually. I used auth()->login($user). But it does not work.

LoginController function

```
public function googleCallback()
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

            $newUser = new User;     
            $response = $newUser->create($user);

            return redirect('/home');
        } 
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
            return redirect('/login');
        } 
    }
```

User.php

```
   <?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable 
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens, HasRoles;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $rememberTokenName = 'remember_token';

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getAuthIdentifierName() {}
    public function getAuthIdentifier(){}

    public function setRememberToken($value){}
    public function getRememberTokenName(){}

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->getAttribute('password');
    }


    public function getReminderEmail() {
        return $this->getAttribute('email');
    }


    public function getRememberToken() {
        return $this->getAttribute('remember_token');
    }

    public function create($user){

        try{
            $existingUser = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();


            if(!$existingUser){
                // create a new user
                DB::transaction(function () use($user){
                    $newUser                  = new User;
                    $newUser->name            = $user->name;
                    $newUser->email           = $user->email;

                    if(isset($user->token)){
                        $newUser->access_token    = $user->token;
                    }
                    else{
                        $newUser->access_token = $user->createToken('press_bell')->accessToken;
                    }

                    $newUser->assignRole('customer');
                    $newUser->save();
                });

                $userObj = User::find($newUser->id);
                auth()->login($userObj);
                return response()->json(["status" => 200, "data" => $newUser, "success" => "User created successfully"]);
            }
            else{
                $userObj = User::find($existingUser->id);
                auth()->login($userObj);
                return response()->json(["status" => 200, "data" => $existingUser, "success" => "User created successfully"]);
            }


        }catch(Exception $e){
            dd($e);
            return response()->json(["status" => 500, "error" => "System Error! Please try again."]);
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to dd(Auth::user()) in loginController then it displays me this, 
[image]

> But if i try to dd(Auth::user()) in home.blade, it Shows NULL. Please
>   help me with this.

Comment: "it does not work", so what happens?

Comment: It does not give any error. but it fails to give me logged user's information. It also fails at auth middlerware and everytime redirects to "login" page. @lagbox

Comment: I have added some more code. Please check now @lagbox

Comment: what do these routes look like, what middleware is assigned, etc

Comment: Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['auth'],
    ], function () {                                                                       
  Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home')->name('home');                            });                                                                                                                       
  @lagbox

Comment: if you have the `auth` middleware on the home route and they can reach it, they are authenticated, are you returning the `home` view in some other route as well?

Comment: No. Only after the user is authenticated, home view is rendered. @lagbox

Comment: @lagbox Hello! can you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the `create` method is called from a Facebook or Google callback, you are **authenticating the Facebook/Google service** and not the user.

`auth()->login(..)` authenticates the current caller.

You are to call `auth()->login(..)` in a method that the user calls directly, e.g. the "redirected to" page or similar.

Comment: the user is redirected to the provider, they are then redirected to that callback with extra data after the provider authorizes ... oauth authorization code flow